# Show deactivated/disabled products in comparison view

Tags: magento-1.8, compare

I am trying to show a product in comparison view, which is set as `status = disabled` through admin panel.

In default magento, this seems not possible as the disabled products are not visible in *product listing page* as well as *product details page*.

Somehow, I managed to show the disabled products in *product listing page* and *product details page* by overriding `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product`.  In that I commented the following code:

```
    // if (!$this->canShow($product)) {
    //     return false;
    // }
```

Now, please someone help me on how to show up the disabled product even in comparison view?

Comment: If it is not critical you can try to make all disabled products enabled but with limited visibility.

Comment: @Tim In my project, a disabled product is referred as discontinued product. but still some users want to do comparison with a discontinued product. As I mentioned above I am able to get success in product listing as well as product details page which is a 90% success to me. If I anyhow manage to cross this comparison view then this will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a long time and failing to extract a solution from mage core files, I created an attribute which does the same as `status` attribute. I named that attribute as `Archive` (Yes/No). This new attribute will justify whether a product is discontinued or not.

Atlast, I filter all my product listing, product details and home page related to this new attribute `Archive` only.

I am planning to write a MVC action, which will change all the products `status` as `enabled` and at the same time triggering the `Archive` as yes for the `status = disabled` products. I will share the code here soon.